# Constructing the Normal CDF $Z$-tables?

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

One topic that is always bypassed (in my experience, at least) in an undergraduate statistics course is the construction of $Z$-tables, such as the one provided at this link https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf.

[image]

It is shown in a calculus-based statistics course that such tables are constructed using (I've heard "difficult" used to describe these) numerical approximations of the integral
$$F(z) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{z}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}\text{ d}t\text{.}$$
Back before computers existed, how did people construct these tables? [Note that I have *very* little background in numerical analysis.]

Comment: Similar in principle to the computer numerical approximations, with a greater emphasis on interpolation.

Comment: An interesting tool for measuring areas on paper (while not suitable for this accuracy used here) is the Planimeter, just thought it might be interesting for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q(x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$ denote the complementary standard Gaussian distribution function, and $\phi(x)$ the standard Gaussian density function. Many
scientific calculators evaluate $Q(x)$ for $x \geq 0$ via a
rational function approximation:
$$Q(x) \approx \phi(x)(b_1t + b_2t^2 + b_3t^3 + b_4t^4 + b_5t^5) 
~~ \mbox{where}~ t = \frac{1}{1 + 0.2316419x},$$
$b_1 = 0.319381530$, $b_2 =  0.356563782$,
$b_3 = 1.781477937,$
$b_4 = 1.821255978,$ and
$b_5 = 1.330274429.$  The magnitude of the error in the approximation is smaller
than $7.5 \times 10^{-8}$ for all $x \geq 0$. This suffices to calculate the table
that you have exhibited.

The formula stated above is essentially Formula 26.2.17 in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_932.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, a "computer" was a person sitting at a desk, perhaps with an adding machine, and doing calculations.  See e.g. [The Human Computer and the Birth of the Information Age](http://www.philsoc.org/2001Spring/2132transcript.html).

Comment: Misleading answer (but nice link).